# Android adb screencap - скриншот плохой и хороший

Tags: android, screenshots, adb

нужно снимать скриншоты с приставок, которые крутят рекламу. На приставках включен adb. Делаю скриншот так:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png && adb pull /sdcard/screen.png
```

Но в большинстве случаев получаю картинку с одним лишь альфа-каналом. Пример тут: [image: плохой скриншот]
Думал дело в формате видео, но иногда, по неизвестной причине, скриншоты получаются нормальные на тех же видео. Потом снова что-то случается и опять только альфа канал. Пробовал на мониторах и телевизорах разной диагонали и разрешения - одно и тоже. Кажется, что дело связано с видео, потому что когда видео не идёт - скрины всегда нормальные (рабочий стол, заставка).
В приложении видео проигрывается через медиа-плеер:

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
```

В чём может быть дело ? Посоветуйте, подскажите.